# Is it possible to access localStorage & Web SQL data on an mobile device?

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, local-storage, web-sql

As far as I know, there isn't a way to bring up a developer console in a browser for a mobile device; however, is there a way to get to this data via native OS API?  Or perhaps by connecting the device to a computer and navigating it's folder?

Answer (score 0):

M. I'm not sure what you mean by accesing web SQL data on a mobile device.

As far as debugging, you can turn on the debug console in the safari properties on an iPhone. (settings > safari > advanced > debug console). This will let you see console logs and JS errors.

For local storage, there are a few options. You can use HTML5 local storage as detailed in this blog post on the development of the linkedin mobile app. (http://engineering.linkedin.com/mobile/linkedin-ipad-using-local-storage-snappy-mobile-apps)

Comment: here is a reference to PhoneGap's JavaScript file-system access library. I know Phone gap has a library that can access mobile devices file-system. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File

Comment: Thank You for the link.  I apologize for not being clear with my original question.  What I would like to know is if there is a way to access localStorage or the client-side dB without using code.  On a desktop version of Safari/Chrome, I can bring up the developer console and type localStorage.myProperty and see the value.  Also, if I bring up the console, I can expand the Databases node uner the Resources menu and see the dB's that were created for the device.  What I would like to know is if it's possible to do the same thing on a mobile device?